# meaning of "Loop epicenter"

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what is loop or Loop epicenter in this sentence?
I guess it is a place when a road runs a loop but I am not sure.

A closer look at the map, in which dark colors represent higher median income levels, shows patches of dark jade starting in the city’s Loop epicenter and running north, along Lake Michigan.

http://www.eater.com/a/starbucks-income-map

Comment: @KristinaLopez I suggest putting that as an answer. You would probably get credit for that.

Comment: "Epicenter" , like "leverage" is one of those self-important words that comes into vogue from time to time and which becomes nearly meaningless through overuse. _Center_ would have worked just as well. Taken from seismology, _epicenter_ as commonly used might suggest the place from which something radiates - like influence, but that isn't implied by the given context.

Comment: I believe that "epicenter" has (or once had) a meaning in mathematics.  In addition, the term is used as a technical term when discussing both earthquakes and explosions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Loop" they're referring to is the "downtown" section of Chicago that is "looped" by the elevated train tracks (the "El") - as shown in the map below. The epicenter is the physical center of the Loop.

[image]